# Navigate to a contact from list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So at the moment I have a contacts list where I can view my contacts in a static list.  I want to be able to click on the search bar, and instead of it dropping over the contacts, obscuring users view, the search will open up in a new blank page

```
 class _ContactPage extends State<ContactsPage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          home: new Scaffold(
              appBar: new AppBar(
                title: widget.appBarTitle,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Scaffold's body in a navigator and push a search page onto that navigator when you start typing. Something like this:

```
...

// Declare this at the top
_navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

...

// onChanged method for your search text field
onChanged: (value) {
  if (shouldShowSearchResults) {  // TODO
    _navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('contacts/search');
  } else if (shouldHideSearchResults {  // TODO
    _navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
  }
}

...

// New body for your Scaffold
body: new Navigator(
  key: _navigatorKey,
  initialRoute: 'contacts',
  onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == 'contacts') {
      return new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => new ContactList(kContacts),
        settings: settings
      );
    } else if (settings.name == 'contacts/search') {
      return new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => new SearchPage(contacts: kContacts, search: searchValue),  // TODO
        settings: settings
      );
    }
  }
)

...
```